# Find the lowest Integer value for a sqrt of a function where the input x and f(x) must be integers

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, quadratics

For this given equation:

$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2bx-c}, x\in\Bbb{Z}$

Where $b, c$ are known, and I know that $x>=1$ I want to find the lowest value for $x$ such that $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}$.

In other words I want to find an integer value for $x$ to give me a an integer value in $f(x)$.

The numbers $b,c$ have both at least 50 digits, in most cases (if not all) we have $2b>c$.

My question is:

1- Is it possible to find the solution in a direct mathematical way to get the integer value given that the number is large.

2- If not, then is there an algorithm to find the solution in sub polynomial time like: $\log(b)+\log(c)$, if not then what is next best thing?

Comment: What are $b,c$?  Rational numbers?  Integers?  Real numbers?  If the latter, there may be no such value.  $x^2+\pi$ is never an integer if $x$ is.  Even if $b,c$ are integers, there may be no such value.  $x^2+2$ is never a square if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: If $b,c$ are integers, this is  [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).  You are looking for pairs of integers $(n,m)$ that satisfy $n^2=m^2+Am+B$ for integers $A,B$.  In your case we can always complete the square to write the quadratic as $(x-b)^2-b^2-c$ and thereby eliminate the linear term on the right.

Comment: Typo:  I accidentally changed the sign on your linear term. I should have written $x^2+2bx-c=(x+b)^2-b^2-c$.  The point I was making is not changed.

Comment: @lulu Yes, b and c are constant integers that I know as well (Everything is integer). And yes I am looking for the integer pairs (n,m) if we write the function in the way you've written. I'll check out the Pell's equation, but from what you're stating it could be the solution.

Comment: What I am trying to find a solution for does indeed fit a Generalized Pell's Equation, if you submit it as an answer I can accept it and thank you for your help.

Comment: I have one more question, I found that my equation simplifies to $x^2-y^2=c$ but Pell's equation states that we need the coefficient of 'y' to be non-square. Is there a way to solve it with Pell's equation still or is it a different type of problem now?

Comment: With coefficient $1$ the equation comes down to factoring. You get $(x-y)(x+y)=c$ so you get a solution every time you can factor $c=n\times m$, so long as $n,m$ have the same parity.

Comment: Thus, this is actually simpler than Pell's equation, though it may require you to factor a large integer.  I'll summarize below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We can remove the linear term on the right as by writing $x^2+2bx-c=(x+b)^2-b^2+c$.  In this way, the problem comes down to seeking pairs of integers $(n,m)$ with $$n^2=m^2+C$$  for some known integer $C$.

But that's equivalent to $$(n-m)(n+m)=C$$

In this way we see that there will be only finitely many solutions $n,m$ as each solution corresponds to a way to write $C=a\times b$ where $a,b$ have the same parity.  Conversely, each such factoring gives you a solution $(n,m)$ so, in this way, the problem comes down to factoring $C$.  Of course, for very large $C$, this might not be easy.